# How to call cgi.FieldStorage?

Tags: python, apache2, cgi, mod-wsgi

In [this document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#using-the-cgi-module), It's said "Instantiate it exactly once, without arguments.". But i got a `KeyError: 'file'`, the return dictionary of `FieldStorage` doesn't have key `file`.

And i followed [this instruction](http://pwp.stevecassidy.net/wsgi/file-upload.html#title2),call it like this

`formdata = cgi.FieldStorage(environ=environ, fp=environ['wsgi.input'])`

Then i can get `formdata['file]` and write the uploaded file to local drive.

Why? What arguments does method `FieldStorage` take? And where can i obtain such documents? I don't know what `fp` stands for

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you're using mod_wsgi, there is no reason to use the cgi module; it's designed for a completely different interface between the Web server and your application.

Comment: Then How to handler uploading files using WSGI?